# Express API work locally but not on Nginx server

Tags: javascript, api, express, nginx, express-router

I've developed an API with Express that work locally but not on server with Nginx, I get a 404 error for each others pages than "/" and I can't figure why. I saw lot of persons recommend to use `app.get` instead of `app.use` but that imply not  using router and my API is quite big so It won't be good for me.

That's my server.js file :

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json({ limit: "100mb" }));

const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");
const jobsRouter = require("./routes/jobs");

app.use("/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/jobs", jobsRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});
```

and here it's the jobs file for example :

```
const express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");

const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const { admin, editor, viewer } = require("../middleware/roles");

let selectedData = require("../data/jobs.json");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", [auth, viewer], (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    selectedData,
  });
});

router.post("/", [auth, editor], async (req, res) => {
  let toPut = {
    id: selectedData.length + 1,
    data1: req.body.data1,
    data2: req.body.data2,
    data3: req.body.data3,
    data4: req.body.data4,
  };
  selectedData.push(toPut);

  fs.writeFile(
    "./data/jobs.json",
    JSON.stringify(selectedData),
    function writeJSON(err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
    }
  );

  res.status(200).send({
    selectedData,
  });
});

router.delete("/:id", [auth, admin], async (req, res) => {
  delete selectedData[req.params.id - 1];

  res.status(200).send({
    selectedData,
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

and there my Nginx config :

```
server {

        root /var/www/webiste.com;
        index index.html index.htm index.js index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name webiste.com www.webiste.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/webiste.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/webiste.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.webiste.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = webiste.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name webiste.com www.webiste.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

The fact is that if I put `app.get("/api/jobs", something...)` in server.js it works but not with `app.use` so if you have any ideas of why the router isn't working It will be great !

Comment: Can you be a little more precise about the error? What request are you making? In your `server.js` file you have created an endpoint for `/jobs` and not `/api/jobs`

Comment: Yes I write It wrong, It's `/jobs` and the error is a 404  with `cannot GET /jobs`